# Actionbar or tabs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am little confused between the use of **ActionBar** and **Tabs**. I guess both are using for same thing that is to make some links available throughout app navigation. **ActionBar** can also adjust itself according to screen.It also has library to support earlier versions of android. So what will be the case where we will use tabs or both things together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an action-bar has nothing to do with having tabs. 
The action-bar is a standard feature in your app, which provides navigation but also simply an anchor for the user to know where he is and that he is using your app.

You can easily use tabs under your action-bar, whenever that seems fitted.

I'd suggest you start off by reading your way through Google's opinion of [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) page

and take a look at per [example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos)

To see what are the possibilities of the action-bar.

Comment: Thank you. I read out above links. My questions was about the scenario where tabs fit. I know we can use both of them together.